# Word-wrapping text in element with floating inner-elements

Tags: html, css

I have text/image-posts on my page that are user-contributed. As the site is responsive, I do not have full control about the width of the post-wrapper.
Now if a user enters a word that's too long to be displayed right to the image, it floats under the image, even if I have enabled "`word-wrap: break-word;`"
I know that css-property works on fixed-width elements, but it seems not to work with a floating inner element.

Is there any non-hacky, cross-browser solution to that?

Here is my sample for illustration:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yvwzq/

Comment: You can use `word-break: break-all;` with word-wrap to break word. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crazyrohila/Yvwzq/1/)

Comment: @crazyrohila thanks, you are right, however it looks really weird as it also breaks very short words if they are at the end of a line ("as", "on", "it"...). Don't think it's possible with css to distinguish between longer and shorter words ;)

Comment: Yep. "how long is word?", this cannot be figured out with CSS.

Comment: so to sum it up, using word-break: break-all; is implemented stupidly into browsers atm ;)

Comment: I am sure browsers could be made as sophisticated as any desk top publishing program when it comes to dealing with text, but where would the web be if we all had to pay $99.00 for a browser?

Comment: I don't have to pay anything for Open-Office and it stills manages that task pretty well ;)